# User creation on registrations Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

In my app, I want the user to register this code is showing no error but it is not saving in the database; if guys have any suggestions that would be very helpful. The reason I'm creating in this method because I have lots of other user groups because of that reason I wanna create the database model, form and views in this manner
Thanks in advance

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
ADDCHKS_ID=models.CharField(max_length=16,null=True)
is_active=models.BooleanField(default=False)

class justforfun(models.Model):
Name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
Roll_no=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
User=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Forms.py

```
class just(forms.Form):
Name = forms.CharField(
    label='Name',
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Name',
        'rows':1
    })
)

Roll_no = forms.CharField(
    label='Roll-no',
    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Roll_no',
        'rows':1
    })
)
```

views.py

```
def test2(request):
form=just()
if request.method=='POST':
    
    if form.is_valid():
        user21=User.ojects.create(
            username=form.data["Name"],
            password=str(random.random(000000000000,999999999999))
        )
        user21.save()
        just_data=justforfun.objects.create(
            user=user21,
            Name=form.data["Name"],
            Roll_no=form.data["Roll_no"]
        )
        just_data.save()
        
context={
    "form":form
}
return render(request, "just.html", context)
```

Answer (score 1):

The form can *never* be valid, since it is not bounded. You should construct a form with `just(request.POST, request.FILES)`:

```
def test2(request):
    form = just()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = just(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            user21 = User.ojects.create_user(
                username=form.data['Name'],
                password=str(random.random(000000000000, 999999999999)),
            )
            just_data = justforfun.objects.create(
                user=user21, Name=form.data['Name'], Roll_no=form.data['Roll_no']
            )
            return redirect('name-of-some-view')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'just.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: Usually a `Form` or a `ModelForm` ends with a `…Form` suffix,
> to avoid collisions with the name of the model, and to make it clear that we are
> working with a *form*. Therefore it might be better to use `JustForm` instead of
> <s>`just`</s>.

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern <sup>[wiki]</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.